# What is the probability that the sample mean selling price was larger than $156,000?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Assume the mean selling price of new homes in a particular neighborhood in 2015 was \$160,000 while the population standard deviation was \$30,000. Further suppose we have a random sample of 100 homes from the city.

Comment: How does this relate to Mathematica computer software?  If it does not, then probably it belongs in another section of StackExchange, for instance, statistics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is blatantly off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

About medium, I would say. It might also depend on the weather: sunny days are positively correlated with better prices.